# ReactJs state change and value is not what I want

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to build a calendar app to practise.

In the state I have a `current_month: 1`, and  I have a function `IncreaseMonth()` to increase `current_month` but when `current_month` value becomes 12, I want it changed to 1.

I try to use `componentWillUpdate()` lifecycle method to do it, in the code below:

```
componentWillUpdate(prev, next) {
   if (next.current_month == 13) {
     this.setState({current_month: 1})
   }
}
```

But I watch tutorials about lifecycle, which tell me not to use `componentWillUpdate()` to set state.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why not just checking inside the function `IncreaseMonth`whether the current_month is 12, if yes than setState to 1?

Comment: Or you can use `%13` in order to have results with the limit of 12

Comment: You could create a method that checks if `current_month > 12` and then set state there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way would be to move reseting month value into `IncreaseMonth()` method as shown below.

```js
IncreaseMonth = () => {
  let month = 1;
  if (this.state.current_month < 12) {
    month = this.state.current_month + 1;
  }
  
  this.setState({
    current_month: month
  });
}
```

You MUST not set the state in componentWillUpdate() lifecycle event as that event is triggered to indicate that the component is going to be re-rendered, and you can decide within this method whether the component should continue with re-rendering. If this method returns true, the component will be re-rendered. For more information, refer the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate)